# Need to separate month and year input box while using stripe V3

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using [stripe V3](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js) for UI. As far as I found out month and year textbox comes in a single package. Is there any way to separate them out and create two different text boxes in UI?

Comment: That's not something supported in stripe.js, no.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible for a stripe V3 version as they provide month and year in the same package. For date, they provide only one element "cardExpiry".